# Pandas appending suing to_hdf now crashes after updating to PyTables 3.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I recently updated PyTables to version 3.2 in order to circumvent this bug:

https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/447

I am now able to read the data successfully, unfortunately I can no longer append data to an HDF5 store that I need to work with. Specifically, Python crashes whenever I attempt to append to this dataset. The append takes place through pandas as:

`append_df.to_hdf(fname,
                  key,
                  mode='a',
                  format='table',
                  append=True,
                  complib='zlib',
                  complevel=1,
                  min_itemsize={'curve': 120})`

My hunch is this has to do with the necessary additions of the hdf5 and zlib modules, but I am not sure at all. Below is a screenshot of the PyTables update through Anaconda. Thanks you very much in advance.

[image: conda update pytables]

Comment: I had the same issue.  pytables 3.2.0 on enthought canopy.  I had to fall back to 3.1.1.  I'm using pandas default complevel, which I believe is 0.